# href not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using this snippet from [HERE](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/9ymbx). It looks ok, but when I click on a tab, instead of changing the content of the body (`<a href="#tab2success" data-toggle="tab">`), it redirects to **localhost:9000/#tab2success**, which does not exist. How is it possible to achieve this? I just want that when clicking on the tab, it goes to the specific content in the body. Looks like that `href` is not the solution here...

```
 <div class="col-md-9">

      <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1success" data-toggle="tab">Success 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2success" data-toggle="tab">Success 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3success" data-toggle="tab">Success 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1success">Success 1</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2success">Success 2</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3success">Success 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

PD: I'm using angularJS, so if there is any directive or something that could help, it may be also a valid option.

EDIT: Part of my router implementation. It's just o part of the code, because it's too longo to post it all..

```js
angular
    .module('Test', [ //setting a module
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar'
  ])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {

        $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
            //$ocLazyLoad returns a promise that will be rejected when there is an error but if you set debug to true,                       //$ocLazyLoad will also log all errors to the console.

            debug: false,
            events: true,
        });

        // For any unmatched url, redirect to '/dashboard/home'
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard/rank');

        // Now we set up the states
        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', { //parent view
                url: '/dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/main.html',
```

Comment: Do you see any js errors in the console?

Comment: I think you should look into [this](http://stackoverflow.25lm.com/a/33575221)..

Comment: can you also post the routing implementation or states whatever you implement, this is normal in angular it will be defaulted to the specified href value if you didnt configure the routes, take a look into `$routeProvider`

Comment: You are using Bootstrap tabs, but are you importing the corresponding JS file? You are probably missing the code that operates the tabs, located in `bootstrap.js`

Comment: @xxxmatko no, the code works well, it is just that I don't want to change the URL, just the content of the panel, and I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: @MiguelXoelGarcia take a look how to implement nav tabs here http://angularjs.learnwebtutorials.com/tab-panel-angular.html

Comment: @MiguelXoelGarcia the link i posted is the answer for your problem :) Just add activeTab scope property and add checking in your view on what tab was set and it will update the view magically

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi That's it!! Thank you very much! Would you like to post it as an answer or should I do it, to help future people?

Comment: @MiguelXoelGarcia I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior for href's.

To solve your issue please refer to this article :
[Nav tabs in Angular](http://angularjs.learnwebtutorials.com/tab-panel-angular.html)

Basically, there is a flag that controls the visibility of tabs and a `ng-click` event that will update the value for the flag.

Once the value of the model (flag) was updated, it will automatically update the view.

Comment: @MiguelXoelGarcia this is it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the expected behaviour of `href` - if you don't supply a full URL, it'll append it onto your current URL (I'm assuming you are using localhost:9000 while developing). Have a look at [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) which explains how to use it right, utilising `ng-href` directive.

To sum it up, you need to use the "handlebars" format inside the `ng-href` directive:

```
 <a ng-href="{{/#tab2success}}" data-toggle="tab">
```

Comment: will this work? as far as I learn values inside handlebars signifies angular implementation :)

Comment: not working... It changes the selected tab, but not the content of the panel. I want to stay in the same URL, with just changing the content of the panel. Well, it is not my expected behaviour :)

Comment: OP tagged Angular and mentions directives in his question

Comment: In this case the handlebars are obsolete, they should be used only for data binding in `ngHref`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any Angular code or overcomplications. You are just missing the `bootstrap.js` file that operates the tabs.

Make sure you are using the correct classes of the [tab markup](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#markup), import the JS file at the end of the `body` of your document, and that's it.

You can read more about the Bootstrap tabs, the markup, and the way they work in the [official Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

Comment: I'm not missing that. Actually, it was a problem with bootstrap+angular. The solution was here angularjs.learnwebtutorials.com/tab-panel-angular.html